# How can photons destructively interfere?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons, energy-conservation, interference, superposition

This is a concept I don't fully understand. If I have two photons each with frequency $\nu$, then they each have an energy of $E = h\nu$. If they get matched with an inverted phase, then the summed wave will be null due to destructive interference. Then where does the energy go? It cannot radiate, since that would produce an extra E-M wave, right?

Comment: Are you wanting to consider exactly 2 photons and nothing else? Or are you wanting to consider full EM waves and look at two photons within that?

Comment: Electromagnetic waves have frequency and wavelength. Photons are point particles with energy and momentum. For your question it is enough to discuss electromagnetic waves.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of what it was closed as. This question specifically seems interested in photons, not just waves in general.

Comment: Maybe this exposures your question a bit  https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/601091 and the link therein

Comment: Photons are particles. Waves interfere.

Comment: OP is applying classical reasoning to a quantum mechanical problem, this can’t possibly end good. Photons are waves due to wave particle duality. QM guarantees that the total energy of the photon-wave is preserved as expected. OP should read up on quantum mechanics

Comment: As shown by pictures posted by Anna V, the interference pattern is a statistical distribution of individual photons.  Naturally, that REALLY begs the question of exactly what interference really is.

Comment: I think you are asking the right question. Too much attention is given to the "wave" instead of the particle. What is a light wave anyway if not billions of coherent photon particles? Photon frequencies in-phase or out of phase don't effect each others energy while propagating. But at the detection screen opposing phases add up and the contributions are apparent. What experimental proof determined it had to be so called "Light waves" instead of many individual oscillating photons getting diffracted across a detection screen that creates the fringe patterns we observe??

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have complete destructive interference everywhere unless the photons have exactly the wave vector (that is, are propagating in the same direction with the same frequency*).  At some places there is constructive interference, while in some places there is destructive interference.  The total energy, including regions of constructive and destructive interference, is just the sum of the energies of the constituent waves.

Consider, as a simple example, two waves (of equal amplitude and polarization) traveling in opposite directions (and, for now, only worry about their electric fields),
$$\vec{E}_{1}(\vec{r},t)=E_{0}\hat{\epsilon}\cos(kz-\omega t)\\
\vec{E}_{2}(\vec{r},t)=E_{0}\hat{\epsilon}\cos(-kz-\omega t)$$
When you add these together, you get a standing wave
$$\vec{E}=\vec{E}_{1}+\vec{E}_{2}=2E_{0}{\hat\epsilon}\cos(kz)\cos(\omega t),$$
for which the time-average of the electric energy density** $u_{E}=\frac{\varepsilon_{0}}{2}\vec{E}^{2}$ is
$$\langle u_{E}\rangle=\varepsilon_{0}E_{0}^{2}[1+\cos(2kz)].$$
There are places [nodes, where $2kz=n\pi$ for $n$ odd], where the electric energy density is zero because of destructive interference; and there are places [antinodes, with $2kz=n\pi$ for $n$ even] where it is *four* times that of each original wave, because of constructive interferences.  Averaged over all space, the total energy is twice that of a single propagating wave—exactly what we expect for a system with two waves.

*If you really want to consider two waves with *identical* wave vectors, then you cannot *emit* a second photon that is $180^{\circ}$ out of phase with the first.  Generating an electric field with that phase is actually *absorbing* the first photon, not emitting another one.

**The magnetic energy has as similar structure, but it is situated slightly differently spatially, because there is an additional relative minus sign between the magnetic fields $\vec{B}_{1}$ and $\vec{B}_{2}$ of the two waves.

Comment: I think the key here is in your first "*".   A  complication is that you can't really create a wave with a single wave vector nevermind two with identical wave vectors.  But apply the same question to point sources.  Again, you can't put the two sources in exactly the same place.  But in an imaginary world where you can (dangerous: your results are always meaningless if physics is applied to unreal situations) I think  you have to conclude that each source does such work on the other that the energy remains in the system to be dissipated in whatever mechanism is driving the sources.

Comment: I think the question is about photons, and this answer is about classical EM waves

Answer (score 3):

In the  present day physics [standard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) photons are elementary particles , on par with the other particles in the table. This means they are point particles, of fixed (in this case zero) mass with spin 1 and $E=hν$ . The $ν$ is the frequency that the classical light will have, as it is composed of zillions of photons This  can [can be seen](https://www.sps.ch/artikel/progresses/wave-particle-duality-of-light-for-the-classroom-13/) experimentally, how classical interference appears because the beam  is composed out of a large number of same energy photons.

[image: wavepart]

> camera recording of photons from a double slit illuminated by very weak laser light. Left to right: single frame, superposition of 200, 1’000, and 500’000 frames.

Single photons leave a point  consistent with the particle nature. **It is the accumulation of photons that shows the classical interference pattern.**

So two photons will not interfere in any way, except if one is studying [photon photon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-photon_physics) scattering, which is very improbable for low energy photons. For high energy photons, gamma rays, a lot of particle antiparticle pairs can be created and there are plans of [gamma colliders](https://www.slac.stanford.edu/pubs/beamline/26/1/26-1-kim.pdf).

So there is no problem with the individual photons, they do not interfere. It is the wavefunction of the set up ( in the case above  "photon scattering through two given slits given distance apart") that carries the frequency information of the photon, and can thus appear in the probability distribution.  This should not be surprising as it is a [quantized maxwell equation](http://cds.cern.ch/record/944002?ln=en) that gives the photon wavefunctions.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is correct, photons do not really interfere. The DSE taught at the high school level is a convenient theory and it also works well mathematically but 2 photons cancelling is a violation of conservation of energy. In university in quantum optics courses deeper explanations are provided.

Think of 2 tsunamis one from Japan and the other from USA, starting with opposite phase .... when they meet (at say Hawaii) they cancel and Hawaii is saved ... but a second later the waves emerge again and continue on their way to Japan and USA, the energy was only stored temporarily in the elasticity of the water! The energy will only be absorbed when the wave crashes on the land. For photons we can never really observe the field directly ... we can only see a photon when our eye or camera absorbs it. We assume the photons are interfering in the EM field .... it makes sense .... but every photon is created by an atom and eventually absorbed by an atom.

Comment: Dear PhysicsDave. It is usually frown upon to directly copy-paste [identical answers](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/589697/2451). (The problem is if everybody start to copy-paste identical answers en mass.)

Comment: @PhysicsDave what is "elasticity of the water"?

Comment: @RogerWood  check out wikipedia, water elasticity and compressibility.

Comment: @PhysicsDave Tsunamis as surface gravity waves. Nothing to do with elasticity.  The same earthquake may generate longitudinal (acoustic) waves which do involve a liquid's bulk modulus (elasticity).

Comment: @RogerWood Take 2 waves in a pond of opposite phase (a frog jumps in as a frog jumps out) when the waves meet they cancel, the water is calm, but only for a short time, the waves will reemerge and continue along their path, that's physics.  Where was all the kinetic energy stored when the water was calm for that brief second?

Comment: @PhysicsDave (I like the frog analogy)  For gravity waves, the energy at a given point oscillates between potential energy (water height) and kinetic energy (water velocity). Two colliding wave-trains will produce a standing wave pattern for the duration that the two wave-trains overlap. At a node (zero of wave height) in the standing wave pattern, the energy resides in the velocity of the water as it sloshes back and forth between the wave peaks on either side.

Comment: @RogerWood In a wave tank with standing waves at the when the water is momentarily flat I guess you are saying velocity is max .... even though it looks still ... it isn't.  Maybe the elasticity is relevant for waves in air or a guitar string. (?). The point was not to have a medium where energy is lost.

Comment: @RogerWood Now I'm thinking about 10 frogs in/out, i.e. 2 wave trains of opposite phase that are 10 cycles long. The water at first contact is calm for 10 cycles, i.e. no kinetic energy.!?

Comment: @PhysicsDave That's interesting to think about. Gravity waves are very dispersive (group velocity is half phase velocity), so it's difficult to make a train of 10 cycles that starts and stops abruptly as it propagates. Nevertheless, I think you're right, the two wavetrains traveling in opposite directions will create instants in position where there's no vertical motion (standing wave).  There will also be one instant in time when all 10 cycles overlap and cancel and the surface will be completely flat. Although amplitudes cancel, velocities will add ...

Comment: @PhysicsDave ... since they're traveling in opposite directions.   So, same as before, the water may seem flat and stationary at a given instant in space or in time, but it's actually moving. A small displacement in space or time will show amplitude as well as velocity.